# delete facebook likes, reset whole id likes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

i had some Problems with my og:meta Tags and destroy the Like function.
Now every Picture in my gallery and my gallery have 9 Likes.
I would like to delete or reset all likes.
Is it possible to delete them?

the gallery is based on php without mysql.
The link to the gallery is build like
http://domain.tld/pictures.php?gallery=nameofgallery
the link to the pictures
http://domain.tld/my-picture.php?gallery=nameofgallery&picture=picture.jpg

now i have correct all mistakes in my Page, there was a wrong redirect and
this gives a bad url and a bad picture name.

i don´t know much about FB and og functions. it was hard for me to get the button 
working.

Can someone help me?

regards

Comment: No, deleting these likes would only be possible for the users that made them in the first place. Only thing you can do is change the URLs, so that new likes would be made on different URLs, so you would have a “fresh start” with those new URLs having zero likes in the beginning.